# script function wont work after I use .load() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am adding data inside a table and I am preventing page to reload, so I use load function to just load the table and fetch data from it without reloading the page.

Sample output:
[image]

And then after I add payment: 
[image]

I use this code to load the data without reloading the page:

```
$('#payment-body').load('client-info.php?id='+c_id+' #payment-body');
```

And now my problem is. As you can see there is X icon after the printer icon.

I set function with that icon. here is the function:

```js
    $(".remove-transaction").click(function()
    {
    var p_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var c_id = $(this).attr("name");
    var remove_payment = $(this).attr("id"); 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'proccess.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {'p_id':p_id,'c_id':c_id, 'remove_payment':remove_payment},
        beforeSend : function(){
            $("#status").fadeIn(0).delay(2500).hide(0);
            $("#recieptModal_"+p_id).modal("hide");
            $("#statusModal").modal("show");
            $(".header-status").html('<h4>Please Wait...</h4>');
            $("#status").html('<h3 class="center"><em class="fas fa-sync fa-spin checking-client"></em> &nbsp; Deleting Payment...</h3>');
        },
        success: function(response){
            $("#status").fadeIn(0, function(){
                $(".header-status").html('<h4>Done!</h4>');
                $("#status").html('<h3 class="center"><em class="far fa-trash-alt invalid-client"></em> Payment Removed!</h3>');
                $("#payment-row"+p_id).fadeOut('slow');
                $('#total-paid').load('client-info.php?id='+c_id+' #total-paid');
                $('#total-balance').load('client-info.php?id='+c_id+' #total-balance');
                $('#remarks').load('client-info.php?id='+c_id+' #remarks');
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#statusModal").modal("hide");
                }, 3000);
            });
        },
        error: function(error){
             console.log(error.responseText);
        //you could debug your php code if some error raises
        }

        });
    });
```

It is working when I reload the page. But what I want to happen is make it work without reloading the page. Or as you can see. just using .load() function.

Comment: you can try to load the script too.

Comment: I tried but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this, I think it is because the newly appended data function will not work,

```
 $(document).on('click', '.remove-transaction', function(){
```

Comment: yes its because it is newly appended. I tried this one but its still the same. thanks for answer.

Comment: try doing this on the function, `$(this).closest('tr').hide();` if it will remove the row, just that function inside no other else

Comment: I figured out the problem. js is not working on (load function). It just load its content and not load reading other content.

Comment: you can use `.append()` though, but anyway congrats

Comment: I update your answer. Thanks :-) and now its working.